# Python return (login,password) or null-alike

Tags: python

Imagine that I have a weird auth form, where users literally need to type "LOGIN login password" (ex. LOGIN john qwerty) and I want to create a function that checks that `login` and `password` are correct and return something like `(True, login, password)` if they are correct indeed or `(False`) without any additional info. So I want to get something like this

```
def is_text_in_correct_format(text):
    if len(text.split()) == 3:
        flag, login, password = text.split()
        try:
            // some checking here
            return (True, login, password)
        except Exception as err:
            logging.exception(err)
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

How can I do that?

P.S. I understand that this design is weird as its best but still.

Comment: Do you really need the `try - except`? Wouldn't it be enough to use `if` and `else` in the part where you wrote "some checking here"?

Comment: BTW, I strongly suggest to keep the return value consistent. If you return a tuple if everything is OK you should return a tuple when the check didn't succeed too. You could return something like `(False, None, None)`. Otherwise every caller will have to check the type of the returned value.

Comment: @Matthias Yesss!! Thats what I want to achieve but in the best possible way

Comment: Are you asking what to put instead of `// some checking here`? That depends on where you're saving the user details

Answer (score 0):

Here's something *super* simple you could do: just have a dictionary (or really, any kind of database you want) with all of the stored `login:password` pairings, and check for validity that way.

```py
# user data goes in this dict
UserData = {'john':'qwerty'}

def is_text_in_correct_format(text):
    if len(text.split()) == 3:
        flag, login, password = text.split()
        if (login in UserData) and (UserData[login] == password):
            return (True, login, password)
        else:
            return (False, None, None)
```

You don't really need the try/except, I think. Additionally, my `else` returns a tuple in the format of the successful tuple, and not just the boolean; this will hopefully minimize any potential database errors.

You could also add another check if you wanted variable action depending on what the first word of the entered phrase was. As written, the code will work for the command "LOGIN john qwerty" as well as "PLEASEDONTLOGIN john qwerty" :).